# Automatic processing of dymola simulation results with Python

Tags: python, mat, modelica, dymola

I want to automatically evaluate my simulation results with a python script, but struggle to open the .mat-Files in a meaningful way.

Opening the files with scipy.loadmat doesn't seem to be a viable option:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
x = loadmat(path)
```

Result: 
[image]

Should I implicitly return the values I want to analyse with my python simulation script or is there another way of loading .mat-Results with Python?

What do you use for such tasks? Matlab is not an option sadly.

Comment: You could try using DyMat: https://pypi.org/project/DyMat/

Comment: @matth this is pretty much the answer to my question! Can you post this as the answer? Thank you so much!

Comment: So, is the mat file from Dymola/Openmodelica not a "standard"-conform .mat file?

Comment: Another way could be, since you'll be using Python anyway, to use [OMPython](https://github.com/OpenModelica/OMPython).

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48662401/how-can-i-analyse-the-results-of-a-dymolasimulation-simulated-via-python-interf

Comment: Phil, if you [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question, by giving a small example script, I would definetly upvote it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By suggestion from @matth [DyMat](https://pypi.org/project/DyMat/) can be used to write code to automatic process dymola results:

```
import DyMat

d = DyMat.DyMatFile(path) 
varX = d.data("dymola.path.to.variable")
```

To get all the paths to all variables one can use `d.names()` or `d.nameTree()`